# Problem with NetBeans 12.5 Java System.out.print() and reading text from console

Tags: java, netbeans, printing

all the code that is attached has been tested in both NetBeans and Eclipse on two different computers, running perfectly in Eclipse without problems.

If I write the following code everything runs correctly in both NetBeans and Eclipse:

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            System.out.println( "Write something: " );
            String text = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("text -> " + text);
            
        }
        
    }
```

Output writting "hello":

```
Write something: 
hello
text -> hello
```

The problem is with the following code running on NetBeans:

In this example instead of using println() we are using only print().

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
             
            System.out.print( "Write something: " );
            String text = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("text -> " + text);
            
        }
        
    }
```

Running this on NetBeans perpetually will show absolutely nothing until we write something.

Netbeans output writting "hello":

```
hello
Write something: text -> hello
```

Eclipse output writting "hello":

```
Write something: hello
text -> hello
```

Does anyone have a clue as to why and how to fix this? I don't want use Eclipse.

---

Using System.out.flush() does nothing to this problem.

```java
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
             
            System.out.print( "Write something: " );
            System.out.flush();
            String text = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("text -> " + text);
```

[link to a gif showing the original problem](https://gyazo.com/edaaba3942420007d65ea86113098a8a)

[link to a gif showing the problem using System.out.flush()](https://gyazo.com/edaaba3942420007d65ea86113098a8a)

Comment: Due to buffering of the output?  Use System.out.flush();

Comment: You can use java.io.Console which allows more, and does these kind of no-newline prompts.